# Whats my Azure VM administrator user name

Tags: azure

My laptop is not working, so I'm trying to create an rdp connection to my azure VM on another computer. I do remember the password but not the username. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 36):

[Update] - [26 March 2020]
Now with updated Azure screens and view, we do not have option to retrieve Azure VM username from portal but there is a workaround.

- Go to "Reset Password" on the left pane of your Azure portal window for your VM. Now add username and password and update.
  With this new username and password, you can login to VM machine and find your old/original username.

[OLD ANSWER - Not Valid Now]:
While troubleshooting I tried to find the newly created VM's username with below steps, I hope this will help someone.

1) Go to "Virtual Machines" section on your Azure portal.

2) Select your newly created Virtual Machine name.

3) Click on the "Connect" link just next to the "Start" in the selection bar.

4) There will be a new blade opened for you on the right, with two tabs "RDP" and "SSH".

5) Select the "SSH", there next to the "Login using your VM local account" you find ssh yourusername@"VM's IP address".

you can use yourusername to login to the machine with required password.

Comment: Hi, when is this password set ? When the VM is created ? I need to work on a VM I didn't create so I wonder wha'ts the usual process

Comment: Yes, at the time of VM creation you define the username and password to access the VM. You can access the VM using RDP (Windows) or SSH (Linux) with the defined credentials.

Comment: This isn't true - I saw my username on the SSH tab (even though I don't have SSH enabled on my Windows VM)

Comment: @mjaggard, thanks for sharing. azure portal is a dynamic place. they add and remove features every day.

Answer (score 13):

**Actually you can see it, Windows or Linux VM's:**

**1.** Through VM resource --> Connect --> SSH

[image]

**2.** Also, you can use **"Run command"** for virtual machine **Linux**:

[image]

, and for virtual machine on **Windows**:

[image]

**3**. You can use PowerShell:

```
Get-AZVM -Name *vmname* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OSProfile
```

[image]

You can also use **Serial Console** down in **Support + troubleshooting** in case you experiencing issues with RDP or SSH connection. Or reset your password with **Reset password** in the same block.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use the `ssh -i [*.pem] [user]@[ip.address]` method in one of the screen shots. This is how I was able to connect to my newly created Ubuntu VM with my downloaded private ssh key.

Answer (score 6):

I hope you were able to find your username in 3 years. I have the same issue and found the solution. Answering for new comers.

Just click "configure" button on the VM overview page.
[image: VM-Overview page]

Answer (score 5):

Just check the "Login using VM local account" field. It will have the username of your VM
[image: VM-Username]

Answer (score 2):

You can also find username in **[Home > Resource groups > XXXX - Deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq0Sl.png)** and click Template. This Template will be a json key value pair file. Refer to the attached screenshot.

You can also click on [Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGNCT.png) above Template and it will provide you with adminusername.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your username from PowerShell or Azure CLI:

```
az login
(az vm list | ConvertFrom-Json).osProfile.adminUsername
```

Azure CLI Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a good article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-rdp) on how to change the build-in Admin accounts credentials. Try with this approach, as there is no other way to get your user name.

Answer (score 0):

It is visible when you try to connect to your vm using ssh as mentioned in above answer.
You can also find it under "Automation Scripts" tab. Under 
Automation script -> Template, search for "adminUsername"

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer as wlel as and the best solution for me was to run Powershell command Get-Localuser. Run using the RUN Command on the VM.

The fix RDP issue did not work for me and as soon I got my username I was in.

Might be an old post but might help others because I did not see a single post with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the user name for an existing VM -

Go to the windows VM – Select Export Template from the left under Automation -> Choose Deploy -> Choose Edit Template -> Then from the template you can search for “adminUsername” and you can find the Username from there.
[VM_Username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTufd.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way.
First select your virtual machine, and then at right top corner, click on Json View (1) and here you can see your username (2), [image: Azure Visual Machine username view in Json]