# reveal dbpassword and vmpassword variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a devops project from azure portal.

I choose an ASP.Net Core application, SQL Database and Virtual Machine option.

I have 2 variables in azure devops release pipeline: dbpassword and vmpassword.

I need to connect to my sql database, and to my vm by hand.

How can i reveal the value of this 2 variables ? They are not shown (asterisks)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from the context clues that you used the [Azure DevOps starter apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/)

There is documentation for gaining access to the SQL database here. You will need to [reset the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-sql-database?#connect-to-the-azure-sql-database).

I don't see it explicitly in the docs for starter apps but you can reset the VM password [in the portal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354480/12772788).

In both cases make sure you update those values back in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any asterisks value add simple inline powershell task with:

`$dbpassword.ToCharArray() -join " "`

Copy and remove spaces, not best sollution, but should do the job

Comment: There are no properly way to do that ?

Comment: how did you create those 2 variables, are they being created inside script in pipeline? I am assuming there are not there `pipelines>yourpipeline>edit>variables`
also regarding secrets, one place to keep them handy is azure key vault, stored safe and you can access them by cmdlet

Comment: Those 2 variables has been created automaticaly during devops project creation from azure portal. I cannot see variables in pipelines>yourpipeline>edit>variables, but i can see them in releases>myrelease>edit>variables

Comment: No, i can only see asterix. And your powershell returns -1 (no error message)

Comment: what if you press on padlock in variable section, you should be able to change type of variable from secret to text. Regarding powershell task is `$dbpassword` returning ***?

Comment: It puts a blank string